# What happens if I install two packages that share a shell command?

Tags: bash, package-management

For example, `gprolog` and `swi-prolog-nox` both provide `prolog`. If I install them both, how can I choose between them, and what does, say, `bash` or `sh` do if I just type `prolog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will depend on what the packages install. There are a few different possibilities:

1. Both packages install an executable to the same directory.

   If both provide, for example `/bin/prolog`, then whichever package was installed last will overwrite the one installed before and you will end up with one version of `prolog`. That, however, isn't very common since `dpkg` will complain about conflicting packages and refuse to install if you try to install both.
2. Each package installs the executable in a different path.

   For instance, one in `/bin/prolog` and the other in `/usr/bin/prolog`. Then, which one is run when you run `prolog` will depend on which one is first in your PATH. On Ubuntu systems, the default PATH is:

   ```
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
   ```

   Since `/usr/bin` is before `/bin`, that means that `prolog` will run `/usr/bin/prolog`. You can see what will happen in your system by running:

   ```
   type -a prolog
   ```

   This will print all `prolog` executables (or functions or aliases) found and then run `echo $PATH` to see your PATH and figure out which will be called first.
3. The programs might provide you with a `prolog` command by adding an alias or a function to your shell's startup files.

   In this case, the alias or function will always be executed before any standalone executable. So if you have an alias *and* a `/usr/local/bin/prolog` file, then `prolog` will always run the alias and never the file.

Comment: Regarding (1) this usually results in an error from dpkg which notes that the file was already installed by a previous package.

Comment: @KristopherIves yes, I know. Isn't that clear from my answer? "*That, however, isn't very common since you should be warned of conflicting packages if you try to install both.*"

Comment: It's not a warning it's an error and dpkg will not install the package requested.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I didn't mean warning as in "print it and go on". That wasn't very clear.